# Dell latitude e6430 crash

Tags: laptop, crash

My laptop boots up as normal,but using for like 10-15 minutes, screen goes black and there is red vertical line on the right side of the screen. The only thing you can do is restart it and use it again.

Comment: What steps have you tried for troubleshooting? This sounds mostly like a hardware issue. You can try resetting or refreshing Windows to make sure it’s not an OS issue before reinstalling display/GPU drivers or confirming it’s a hardware issue.

Comment: Well after reinstalling windows it seems it doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Great!! Should I put in my comment as an answer for you to accept?

Comment: Sure. You can do it.

Comment: Run the pre boot diagnostics built into the laptop>>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln115162/resolve-hardware-issues-with-built-in-and-online-diagnostics-supportassist-epsa-epsa-or-psa-error-codes?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try reinstalling Windows. A faulty operating system can sometimes cause your computer to misbehave. Windows can be reinstalled by resetting or refreshing your PC via Settings or Windows Defender. If you would like to preserve all your settings and files, you can use the Media Creation tool’s upgrade this PC option. If a reinstall of Windows doesn’t work, then you can try reinstalling driver’s for the GPU and Display. You can do this by right clicking on the GPU and Display under Display Adapters or Displays, then clicking update drivers, other, and manually Install the recomended drivers. If none of these work, your computer has a hardware issue and might need to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a hardware issue.  Based on your lone observation, in that it fails after working for a while, is that thermal expansion is breaking a solder joint or something similar.

Is it worth fixing?  In my opinion, probably not.  Depending on the issue, even if can be found, might exceed the cost of buying a replacement.  You can find motherboard replacements fairly cheap, which might be the best option.