# Dell Latitude e6430 Black Screen crash

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, crash, dell-latitude

I have Dell Latitude e6430 laptop,and i have issues. I turn it on use it for like 10-30 minutes and it randomly crashes with a black screen and a vertical red line on a side. The only way to turn it off and turn it on again is force shutdown or wait for 10 mins and it shutdowns automatically. Mostly this happen when playing games. I checked CPU temp, it wasn't overheating.

There is a picture of a line(the file too large so i. posted a link.) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9twCm.jpg

Comment: Very likely an hardware failure. Please contact tech support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dell latitude e6430 crash](https://superuser.com/questions/1555105/dell-latitude-e6430-crash) Please don't post duplicates. Literally all your questions here are about the same problem that you've been dragging for a year. You won't get any different answer than those and again, it's an hardware issue.